# Video Texture Module Resolution?

Tags: texturing, scripting, game-engine, video

I got this script from a tutorial:
http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/VideoTexture/VideoTexture_Render_1.html

It allows to set a video texture In the game that's is a render of a camera in real time. For making security cameras monitors for example.
 The only thing I need is to add a command line to scale down the resolution and it will be good to go.
Can Someone Help? See the File.
[image]

Script:

```
import bge

# get current scene
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()

# get the current controller
controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()

# get object script is attached to
obj = controller.owner

# check to see RenderToTexture has been added
if obj.has_key("RenderToTexture") == True:

    # update the texture
    obj["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True)

    # if RenderToTexture hasn't been added 
else:

    # import VideoTexture module
    import VideoTexture

    # get a list of objects in the scene
    objList = scene.objects

    # get camera name being used for render to texture
    camName = obj['cam']

    # get camera object
    cam = objList["OB" + camName]

    # get the texture material ID
    matID = VideoTexture.materialID(obj, "MA" + obj['material'])

    # set the texture
    renderToTexture = VideoTexture.Texture(obj, matID)

    # get the texture image
    renderToTexture.source = VideoTexture.ImageRender(scene,cam)

    # save RenderToTexture as an object variable
    obj["RenderToTexture"] = renderToTexture
```

Comment: oh my! the script box got messed.

Comment: Add four spaces to the start of each line to get a clean script box.

Comment: Looks like it works right to me - if I change the [viewport shading to texture or material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html).

Comment: that's not the thing. it works for me too. but I whant to make the video Texture in a lower resolution

Comment: Lower resolution as in the size of the image shown on the monitors or to pixelate the image? Do you want the same size image on each monitor?

Comment: I need the image shown on the monitors to be very low resolution.

Comment: Are you running this in 2.49?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up the image source specify a [capsize](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_0/bge.texture.html#bge.texture.ImageRender.capsize).

e.g.:

```
source.capsize = [50, 50]
```

Based on your code:

## BGE 2.50+

**setup**

```
import bge

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner

cameraName = owner['cam']
materialName = owner['material']

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
camera = scene.cameras[cameraName]

materialId = bge.texture.materialID(owner, "MA" + materialName)

renderToTexture = bge.texture.Texture(owner, materialId)
owner["RenderToTexture"] = renderToTexture

source = bge.texture.ImageRender(scene, camera)
source.capsize = [50, 50]
renderToTexture.source = source
```

**refresh**

```
import bge

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
controller.owner["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True)
```

[image]

## BGE 2.49

**setup**

```
import GameLogic
import VideoTexture

controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner

cameraName = owner['cam']
materialName = owner['material']

scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
camera = scene.cameras["OB" + cameraName]

materialId = VideoTexture.materialID(owner, "MA" + materialName)

renderToTexture = VideoTexture.Texture(owner, materialId)
owner["RenderToTexture"] = renderToTexture

source = VideoTexture.ImageRender(scene, camera)
source.capsize = [50, 50]
renderToTexture.source = source
```

**refresh**

```
import GameLogic

controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
controller.owner["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True)
```

Comment: aw.. I just copied your code and it doesn't work. I'm using Blender 2.78b

Comment: The above samples are adoptions of the code you posted with your question. Unfortunately it is not the code you use in your sample blend file. E.g. you use different property names. Please adjust either the code or your setup. Ensure you run "setup" (once) before running "refresh" (each frame).

Comment: Thank you! Now I can make a very cheap "filter" Bloom VFX!